# Program output file, that was initially used to compile

Tags: c++

I would like for my program to read in an input file and store the values read as global constants in a constants.h file.

The problem is this constants.h file is specified in my Makefile as a dependency, so it would be empty during compiling time but later gets filled. But my executable wouldn't have access to the new constants.h file, since it was compiled initially with an empty constants.h file.

Is there any way to accomplish what I have described.

Comment: Add another dependency for your constants.h, which would populate it with proper values?

Comment: "prepare" it to get populated

Comment: How do you prepare it to be populated?

Comment: @nm17 why don't u use normal files ?  I'm a noob

Comment: Use the same mechanism that builds missing .o files. Write a program that builds constants.h based on the config file. Add an extra rule to the makefile that builds or rebuilds constants.h based on the configuration file if the configuration has changed or there is no constants.h. That way when the makefile starts walking through the dependencies tree for the target it goes, "Hey, no constants.h!" and executes the rule to build it just like with a missing .o. Or it goes, "Hey, config file changed!" and rebuilds constants.h just like it would with a .o depending on a modified .c file